# Save CSV created by PHP and MySQL to server

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am very close to doing what I need. The file does save to the proper folder and it contains the proper information. However, it is not saving the "," (comma delimited). The file only contains a name and an email like this: name,name@email. But it saving it like this: namename@email.com

Anyway, here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
include "config/config.inc.php";

$from_date = $_GET["from_date"];
$to_date = $_GET["to_date"];
$City = $_GET["City"];
$cityExplode = explode(",",$City);
$cityImplode = "'".implode("','", $cityExplode)."'";

$query = "SELECT * from $dbTablePrefixMaster WHERE Date BETWEEN '".$from_date."' AND '".$to_date."' AND City IN ($cityImplode) ORDER BY Date ASC";

$result = $db->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($db));


if($result->num_rows >0)
{
$delimiter = ",";
$filename = "Upload.csv"; // Trying to save file in server


//create a file pointer
$f = fopen('php://output', 'w');



while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{               
    $lineData =         array(stripslashes($row['Name']),stripslashes($row['Email']));

    fputcsv($f, $lineData);

}

fseek($f, 0);


fpassthru($f);

$filename = "Upload.csv"; // File to Save
file_put_contents("downloads/" . $filename, $lineData);

header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '";');

exit;
}
else
{
//$_SESSION['sess_msg_fail'] = "Sorry, no record found.";
//header("Location: index.php");
}

?>
```

By the way, I did find several tips here on this site, and they helped me get this far, but I cannot find help with the comma delimited problem.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: First, just remove the `$delimiter`, so it should be like `fputcsv($f, $lineData);`

Comment: And second, move the `header` instructions just above the `exit;` line.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Hackerman! I did those two, but so far it's doing the same thing. I edited my code above to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: @Hackerman Can you see anything else I might try?

Comment: Can you add a `var_dump($lineData);` and add the output in your question, I need to take a look at how the variables actually looks.

Comment: Ok, no problem, here is a working sample https://repl.it/repls/IllBackCarriers

Comment: @Hackerman Thank you kindly for your efforts. I have it working now. Can I up vote you for helping? I do not post here often, so I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me as of this posting. Hope it helps someone in the future:

```
<?php
include "config.php";

$from_date = $_GET["from_date"];
$to_date = $_GET["to_date"];
$City = $_GET["City"];
$cityExplode = explode(",",$City);
$cityImplode = "'".implode("','", $cityExplode)."'";

$query = "SELECT * from $dbTablePrefixMaster WHERE Date BETWEEN '".$from_date."' AND '".$to_date."' AND City IN ($cityImplode) ORDER BY Date ASC";
$result = $db->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($db));


if($result->num_rows >0)
{
$delimiter = ",";

$emailArr = array();

while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{       
    if(!in_array($row['Email'],$emailArr))
    {
        $fileContent.= "".stripslashes($row['Rep']).",".stripslashes($row['Name']).",".stripslashes($row['Last_Name']).",".stripslashes($row['Email']).",".stripslashes($row    ['Add1']).",".stripslashes($row['Add2']).",".stripslashes($row['City']).",".stripslashes($row['State']).",".stripslashes($row['Zip']).",".stripslashes($row['PH_Home']).",".stripslashes    ($row['PH_Work']).",".stripslashes($row['PH_Mobile']).",".stripslashes($row['Date']).",".stripslashes($row['Business_Name'])."\n";
        $emailArr[] = $row['Email'];
    }

}

$file = "../folder/folder/folder/Upload.csv"; // File to Save

chmod($file, 0777);
file_put_contents($file, $fileContent);
echo 'echo stuff here';
}
else
{
echo 'no record found';
exit;
}

?>
```